# Task parameters, do reference types point to same memory address on the heap

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, task-parallel-library, task, reference-type

As far as i had understood, when you use a reference type as a parameter in a method, the value on the stack, is copied and the formal parameter therefore points to the same memory address, on the heap, as the original, hence changes are persisted once you have finished with the method.

How does this work with tasks? I have just created 2 new tasks and passed in an array which was declared on the UI thread. Changes made in one of the new tasks were immediately shown in the second task. When i try to change the input(the array) via the UI thread, the same parameter hasnt changed on the 2 new tasks. I was under the impression it should have since they should all be pointing at the same memory location on the heap??

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading;

namespace TasksAndMemory
{
    class Program
    {
        private static ManualResetEvent mre = new ManualResetEvent(false);

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] readToEnd = new int[2];
            int[] data = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
            int valueType = 5;


            int pageCounter = 1;


            Task[] tasks = new Task[2];


            for (int x = 1; x < 3; x++)
            {
                //Needed due to closure problem
                int i = x;

                tasks[i-1] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                {
                    SpecialMethod(data, readToEnd, i, valueType);
                });
            }

            while(pageCounter < 4)
            {
                if (readToEnd[0] == 1 && readToEnd[1] == 1)
                {
                    //Sets the state of the event to nonsignaled, causing threads to block
                    mre.Reset();
                    int[] temp = new int[] { 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12 };
                    data = temp;
                    readToEnd[0] = 0;
                    readToEnd[1] = 0;

                    //Sets the state of the event to signaled, allowing one or more waiting threads to proceed.
                    mre.Set();
                    pageCounter++;
                }
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public static void SpecialMethod(int[] historicalData, int[] readToEnd, int taskNumber, int valueTy)
        {
            int[] temp = new int[] { 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600 };

            for (int x = 0; x <= historicalData.Length; x++)
            {
                if (x == historicalData.Length)
                {
                    readToEnd[taskNumber-1] = 1;
                    mre.WaitOne();
                    x = 0;
                 }
                else
                {
                    valueTy++;
                    temp[x] = temp[x] + taskNumber;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be *much* easier to follow your question if you provided code.

Comment: please excuse any errors, im just trying to test the feasibility of an idea.

Comment: When you say "change the input", do you mean you're changing an element of the array, or replacing it with a new array?

Comment: replacing it with a new array

Comment: In that case, it won't work; the two tasks will still have a reference to the original array.

Comment: the int[] data is acting as a placeholder for data i would be retrieving from a database. I need a way to pause the tasks, update the data they are processing, and then recommence them. the pausing seems to be working. How then can i get the changes in the int[] data to be carried across to the tasks?

Comment: You've shown creating an array, but you never pass that anywhere, contrary to the description in the question.

Comment: Jon Skeet, i may have made a mistake, in which case im sorry, but as far as i can see, i was passing data into the task when they are created. Im then trying to change data in the while(pageCounter < 4). If im missing the point, could you please elaborate, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your analysis seems correct at the start, but your conclusions are not.

You have a reference type (an array) and you pass it to a method by value (which is the default).  This means that the reference to that array, which sits on the heap, is *copied*.

Because both the variable in `SpecialMethod` and `Main` have the same reference, changing the value that they reference will be "seen" by both variables.

That only applies if you *mutate* the array.  That's what you do with `readToEnd`, which is why the sections of code dealing with it work as you intended.

With `data` on the other hand you don't mutate the array, you just *assign a new array to the variable*.  That's changing the reference, not the object that it references, and that's why you're having problems.

As for solutions, there are several.  First, you could change the code to mutate the array rather than assigning a new one; just change the exising values.  If you need to change the number of elements consider using a `List` rather than an array.

Another option is, rather than passing an array, is to add another layer of indirection.  You could make a new class that has a property which is an array, pass an object of that type to `SpecialMethod`, and then you can change that object's property and see it reflected in both locations.  You could use something like this to cover the general case:

```
public class Wrapper<T>
{
    public T Value { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my mistake, i appreciate it. The array is just a placeholder for a datatable, as it was quicker to code up. Is it possible to call the datatables Clear() method when i need to wipe its contents before going to sql server to repopulate it? +1 :)

Answer (score 2):

You create an array:

```
int[] data = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
```

You then pass a *copy* of your *reference* to this array (currently stored in `data`) as a parameter to `SpecialMethod` (via a capture in your original code, but not important, it's still just a copy).

Within `SpecialMethod`, the parameter `int[] historicalData` will receive a *copy* of the reference to this original array.

Thereafter, anything that causes the variable `data` to be reassigned (as opposed to changes made to data within the array *referenced* by `data`) has no effect on any *copies* that were made of its original reference - they're still referencing the original array.

I'm not clear on what your actual requirements are in terms of passing data between threads, so I cannot come up with any firm recommendations. I would usually try to avoid using raw arrays though.

Comment: Thanks very much for taking the time to reply +1 for pointing out mistake as well.